# Is XMLLoader the only way to extract data using Pig?

Tags: xml, apache-pig

I have a simple XML file with a few tags and sub tags.

```
    <tag1 number = 1>
      <tag2 name="Name2" value=value2>something2</tag2>
      <tag3 name="Name3" value=value3>something3</tag3>
      <tag4 name="Name4" value=value4>
        <tag5 name="Name5" value=value5>something5</tag5>
        <tag5 name="Name5.1" value=value5.1>something5.1</tag5> <-- tag5 appears twice
        <tag6 name="Name6" value=value6>
          <tag7 name="Name7" value=value7>something7</tag7>
        </tag6>
        <tag8 name="Name8" value=value8>something8</tag8>
      </tag4>
    </tag1>
    <tag1 number = 2>
      <tag3 name="Name32" value=value32>something32</tag3>
      <tag2 name="Name22" value=value22>something22</tag2> <-different order
      <tag4 name="Name4" value=value4>
        <tag8 name="Name81" value=value81>something81</tag8> <- different order
        <tag6 name="Name6" value=value6>
          <tag7 name="Name7" value=value7>something7</tag7>
-- tag5 is missing, 
        </tag6>
      </tag4>
    </tag1>
```

Is XMLLoader from piggybank the only function to extract data from XML file?
I've found really cool function XMLStreamingLoader ([from Mortar site](http://blog.mortardata.com/post/61678005593/xml-pig-loader)) but it is not open source.
Do I really need to use REGEXP to get data from XML tags?
What is tags are unordered or optional?

Can you provide any more mature function than XMLLoader?